# Does Litho Support Data Binding?

Tags: android, litho

I've been reviewing the documents and I can't find anything talking about whether or not `Litho` supports data binding. There is one comment I've found [here](https://newfivefour.com/android-litho-tutorial.html) that says, "It supports one-directional data binding..." but there isn't anything in the docs that outlines how you might use data binding. So does `Litho` support data binding, if so, how do you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Litho uses declarative approach to building UI, binding comes naturally – you just can't change a property on a View in-place, you need to recreate a new Component. So, when a new data comes from whatever source you have, you'll just recreate a Component and set it to `LithoView` or `ComponentTree`.

Another way is to pass your `Controller` as a Prop, subscribe to data changes and on every update of data, call a State Update for the Component, let's say. For subscribing/unsubscribing you can use `OnAttached`/`OnDetached` methods: https://fblitho.com/docs/onattached-ondetached

Let me know, if you need more info

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you for the response.